# tracial state on a non-unital simple $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I think that there is no tracial state on non-unital simple $C^*$ algebras.Is my thought correct? I 'll appreciate it if anyone can supply me a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not correct. There are simple non-unital C*-algebras that have tracial states.

Maybe not the easiest example, but the so-called Jacelon-Razak algebra is such an example. It is obtained as an inductive limit of certain non-unital C*-algebras, such that the limit algebra has a unique tracial state and is simple.